# unencrypted user credentials accessible from the web app

Tags: web-application, password-policy

I am testing a web app in which there is a section where it is possible to view all the users who can access it with their passwords in clear text. Is it normal this thing?

Answer (score 2):

No detail you have mentioned is supposed to happen:

- being able to view all users
- being able to see passwords
- passwords in plaintext

Unless there is a specific reason for these things and the risks are known and accepted, these would appear to be the result of very poor design practices.

Comment: "View all users" is totally normal for an admin interface. For example, G Suite or Salesforce admin absolutely lets you view all users who can sign into the org. But you're quite right about the passwords!

Comment: @CBHacking one assumes that testing is not done from admin access

Comment: Not necessarily? It depends on the app, certainly you wouldn't expect to get god-mode access over every single user across all organizations or whatever, but when I was a consultant I was routinely provided with admin credentials so I could both directly test admin functionality and create other lower-privilege users to test privilege escalation attacks without needing to guess at what the correct requests to make are. But again, this assumes something where "admin" is a relative term; a G Suite admin can manage all users _in the org_ but certainly not all G Suite users in the world.

Comment: I mean, one would not ask the question the way this one was asked if the testing was done from an admin account. The focus would be on the passwords, not the "users with passwords". Of course it is possible to test with an admin account.

Comment: That's a reasonable assumption, but A) reasonable assumptions - especially around unreasonable situations, which this qualifies as - are how people miss bugs, and B) by the same logic, "one would not" ask "is this normal?" if if wasn't an admin interface because obviously that's extremely abnormal. I'm trying to avoid assumptions about what is reasonable in general. With that said, on priors, I don't think "failed to mention that this is an admin interface" is a _lot_ likelier than "all users can view all user passwords"; that's just... wild. Plausible but wild.

Comment: I'm also assuming that the OP is not a native anglophone and assuming they are not a pro. That's what's informing my interpretation. We can go around and around on this but ultimately, you're saying that one of the points requires a conditional. And I'm saying that the conditional is inherently understood.

Answer (score 2):

No. Hopefully this is only visible to admin users, not to everybody? Still terrible, though. (If the passwords are visible to ordinary users, that's an unmitigated disaster; the app de facto has no authentication controls and - if there are separate privilege levels - no authorization enforcement either.)

In particular, if the passwords are for logging into *this* site, it shouldn't even be *possible* to view them. The server shouldn't be storing the actual value of the passwords at all, and it is a significant vulnerability that it is doing so (it should instead be storing hashes, generated from combining the password with a salt in a slow password hashing function).

To actually *display* the passwords is worse still, though. Bad enough to be a [plaintext offender](https://plaintextoffenders.com/)  without actually explicitly supporting a way to make the DB cough up the user passwords. There's no legitimate reason for that (assuming they're for logging into the current site) and it shouldn't ever be possible.

(Storing passwords in plain text is always bad, but storing them under reversible encryption is sometimes necessary if you are using those passwords to log into *other* sites. However, the login credentials for your *own* site absolutely should be hashed as described above.)

---

Comment: If I wanted to indicate this vulnerability according to the owasp testing guide, how could I classify it in your opinion?